# Ionic 3 How to ensure db data fetched before view is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using token based authentication and token is already saved on DB.

When app starts, I need to fetch the token from DB and make it available before making API calls.

What is best way to do it:

In Component:

```
ngOnit() {
storage.get('token').then((val) => {
    Make api call here 
});
}
```

Or in shared service:

```
getToken() {
    return Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       #if fetched once save in local var and resolve token  
       #or fetch from DB and resolve token  
    })
}

// On Component
this.sharedService.getToken().then((token)=>{
  //Make api call
}
```

Is there any way I can ensure the DB token is fetched and store in shared services before view is loaded? The storage.get is a 'ES6 promise'

Concern is responsibility of loading token before loading view is escalated to any bootstrapping event, so onViewLoad doesn't needs to be defined in each component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented above use case in this way.

I have created `ApiService` for `CRUD` like below.That `code` is self-explanatory and if you need more info please let me know.

*api-service.ts*

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Headers, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private http: Http, private storage: Storage, private events: Events) { }

    createHeader(headers: Headers) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.storage.get('loggedInUser')
                .then((token: any) => {
                    if (token) headers.append('Authorization', 'token ' + token.token);
                    resolve(headers);
                }, err => {
                    resolve(headers);
                });
        });
    }

    get(api) {
        let header = new Headers();
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.createHeader(header))
            .map(() => {
                let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
                options.withCredentials = true;
                options.headers = header;
                return options
            })
            .switchMap((options) => this.http.get(api, options))
            .catch((err: Error | Response) => {
                if (err instanceof Response && err.status === 401) {
                    this.events.publish('token-expiration');
                }
                return Observable.throw(err);
            });
    }

    post(url, params): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            let header = new Headers();
            this.createHeader(header)
                .then(() => {
                    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
                    this.http.post(url, params, options)
                        .subscribe(response => {
                            observer.next(response);
                            observer.complete();
                        }, (e) => {
                            observer.error(e);
                        });
                })
        })
    }

    delete(url) {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            let header = new Headers();
            this.createHeader(header)
                .then(() => {
                    return this.http.delete(url, { headers: header, withCredentials: true })
                        .subscribe(response => {
                            observer.next(response);
                            observer.complete();
                        });
                })
        });
    }

}
```

Here I have created `loggedInUser` storage when the user logged into the app.It is also a `provider` as shown below.

*social-login.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "../providers";
import { LocalCacheServiceProvider } from "../local-cache-service/local-cache-service";
import { UserService } from "../user-provider";
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class SocialLoginProvider {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private localCacheService: LocalCacheServiceProvider, private userService: UserService, private storage: Storage) {
  }

  //login To App
  loginToApp(url: string, data: string) {
    this.apiService.post(url, { access_token: data })
      .map((res: any) => res.json())
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.setUserLocally(res);
      });
  }

  //set User Locally
  setUserLocally(user) {
    this.localCacheService.clearAllKeys().then(() => {
      this.userService.setLoggedInUser(user);
      this.storage.set('loggedInUser', user);
    });
  }
}
```

After that, I can consume above service (i.e. `ApiService`) through any of my `provider` (for `CRUD` operations) as shown below.

This is the `ArticleService`.

*article-service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { config } from '../config/config';
import { ApiService } from './api-service';


@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    }

   getBookById(id) {
        return this.apiService.get(`${config.getBookById}${id}/`).map((res: any) => res.json());
    }  
}
```

Above approach works perfectly fine for me.Hope this approach will help you too.If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: I like the concept of getting and adding token from the api service rather than each component. But isn't fetching token directly from db each time is an overhead, can I use it to store in local variable once fetched?

Comment: I think this is best when we consider the security of the app. I cannot see any performance issue here. And also you can nicely handle token expiration use case too. See `.catch((err: Error | Response) => {
                if (err instanceof Response && err.status === 401) {
                    this.events.publish('token-expiration');
                }
                return Observable.throw(err);
            });`

Comment: Yes, Actually I have stored the `token` inside the `localstorage` i.e. `loggedInUser`.