# http.delete works fine on Postman but not on Angular 4/Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, http, ionic3

I m a beginner in Angular 2/Spring boot stack, so please bear with me a bit.

I have created an `http.delete` method for deleting a particular row selected by the user which prompts an Alert to verify the deletion, my request actually works fine on Postman as I could delete a selected row based on the params given completely from the database, but not in my frontend app, so my API works well as intended.i even checked for Subscribe since Observable are lazy, I did several combinations of code but here's the actual Angular code:

**IncidentService.ts:**

```
supprimerIncident(incident)
{
  let cHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let cParams = new URLSearchParams();
   cParams.set('rfcnumber',incident);
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cHeaders, params: cParams })
   return this.http.delete(Api+'delete',options)

     }
```

And here's the code for the **incident.ts** file calling this service.

```
    deleter(incident:string)
  {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Confirmation',
        message: 'Voulez-vous supprimer ce ticket ?',
        buttons: [{
          text: "Ok",
          handler: () => { 

              this.incserv.supprimerIncident(incident).
             map(res=>res.status)
              .subscribe(res=>
  {
      for(let i = 0; i < this.incidents.length; i++) {

            if(this.incidents[i] == incident){
               this.incidents.splice(i, 1);

              }
  }
    //console.log(this.incidents=incident);

    console.log(res)
   },
    err=>{
  console.log(err);

  return Observable.throw(err.status);
  });
            }
        }, {
          text: "Annuler",
          role: 'cancel'
        }]
      })
      alert.present();


  }
```

The `splice` method works and deletes the intended row from the list, but when I run the app again, the row is back there, it's still in the database, can be deleted directly from Postman, but not the app.
 I appreciate your help and time given, thank you very much.

Edit: here's the screenshot for the request network (xhr request result)

[image]

Comment: You can follow this pattern with your Ionic app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699558/1077309

Comment: Did you check your service does receives the request for deletion?

Comment: I did check it, it doesn't , it returns [object,object]

i'll update the post to include screens of the Xhr

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was the params of the search , i changed the code from

```
supprimerIncident(incident)
{
  let cHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let cParams = new URLSearchParams();
   cParams.set('rfcnumber',incident);
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cHeaders, params: cParams })
   return this.http.delete(Api+'delete',options)

     }
```

to :

```
supprimerIncident(incident)
{
  let cHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let cParams = new URLSearchParams();
   cParams.set('rfcnumber',incident.rfcnumber);
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cHeaders, params: cParams })
   return this.http.delete(Api+'delete',options)

     }
```

"incident" was what returning the [object Object] , i did put a JSON.stringify to verify its content, it held the whole request,wherea i wanted just the rfcnumber as a param for the search for the deletion.

Hope it helps anyone having a similar issue