# How to secure communication between Ionic 3 app and the custom php REST API

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, ionic3

I have a project that includes a web application, a mobile app (Ionic 3) and a REST API module (on HTTPS). 
My main concern is to implement a secure login and communication between them.
Bellow I detail the solution I choose and I want to ask if it is correct and secure.

Steps to follow:

1. on login in the app the server returns a JWT - Acces Token
2. when I call any function from API (except login) I will send the following parameters:

   - inside header: JWT AccesToken (stored in local storage)
   - inside body: any other param necessary to call the API's functions
3. inside every function from the REST API, before execution, I check if the Access token is valid.

Token validation:

a) if the Access token is valid I continue to execute the function and return a value to mobile app

b) if the Access token is NOT valid means I have 2 possible error sources:

- b1) the Access token integrity is compromise -> the returned answer redirect the user to login (this way he doesn't have access anymore to app)
- b2) the Access token expired -> I create a new Access token with the same payload but with new validity. The same time I create the new Access token I also check the IdClient (IdClient is generated from Access Token payload) in DB (if is active, if has the same rights to access the API ... ).  After this I send this new JWT Access token to the mobile app to be used and stored.

This way, I believe I don't have to use a Refresh token, even if the Access Token I used has a limited life period

Is this correct and secure or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I cannot see any problem about the security of your app if you'll implement the above `token based authentication pattern (JWT)`. You can see the same pattern where  I have implemented on one of my `Ionic 3` app using below link.

You can see [**that implementation here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699558/1077309).

But on that app, I had a backend API developer. So I have consumed that API pattern with frontend app. But I would like to have `refresh token pattern` too. Can you tell me why you tried to avoid that on your app?

Comment: I choose not to use RefreshToken because I dont' know how to recall the function after reciving an Acces Token expiration error
To Refresh Token I should do:
A)call SUM1:send variables and Acces Token
B)inside FUNCTION1: I recive the error for Acces Token expiration
C)inside FUNCTION1: I send the refresh Token
D)inside FUNCTION1: I recive the new Acces Token
E)inside FUNCTION1: I recall function SUM1 from the REST API for the new  Acces Token
All this steps must be done inside FUNCTION1. But I dont' know how.
Perhaps use RJx on angular2, "retry/retrywhen"... but I only read about them